# php while loop in an elseif, infinite return of first row

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, while-loop, infinite-loop

So i have a while loop within an if statement that is supposed to go through all of the rows in a database query and list them. however, it just returns one result (the first one) and infinitely lists it. Ive tried everything i can think of and seen and i still get infinite loops.

```
if($result) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $custNum = $row['custNum'];
    $custName = $row['custName'];
    $trackNum = $row['newTrack'];
    $date = $row['pickUp'];

     // only one result        
     if  ( $numrows > 1 ) {

        echo '
           <table>
              <tr>
                 <td>' .$custName. '</td> 
              </tr>'; 

              while($row) {
              echo '
              <tr>
                 <td>' .$trackNum. '</td>
                 <td>' .$date. '</td>
              </tr>';
              };


           echo '</table>';

     } // end of if $numrows

  } // end of if $result
```

Comment: Fetch upon each iteration of the `while` loop: `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate/fetch in every loop.

Try something like this:

```
if($result) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$custNum = $row['custNum'];
$custName = $row['custName'];

 // only one result        
 if  ( $numrows > 1 ) {

    echo '
       <table>
          <tr>
             <td>' .$custName. '</td> 
          </tr>'; 

          while($row) {    
              $trackNum = $row['newTrack'];
              $date = $row['pickUp'];
              echo '
          <tr>
             <td>' .$trackNum. '</td>
             <td>' .$date. '</td>
          </tr>';
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          }


       echo '</table>';

 } // end of if $numrows
```

} // end of if $result

Answer (score 1):

Remember what a loop does: It executes the code from top (while(...)) to bottom (the code right before the closing bracket) and then repeats it. *No other code is executed* as long as you're inside the loop. Now, where is the code that fetches the data from your database? It is *outside* the while loop, so it won't be executed when your while loop goes on. Since you want to fetch new data in each iteration of the loop, you have to include the fetch statement *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

What Cheruvian and Philipp Murray said.

More specifically, a `while` process will process as long as the condition remains true. $row in your original code is established once and when set, remains set and doesn't change, thus remaining true indefinitely.  This is called an infinite loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // execute logic here
}
```

This code snippet works, because `mysql_fetch_assoc` iterates over a record set incrementally and returns `null` when it has completed all records, thus ending the `while` condition.